# How do I make special commands run depending on a scoreboard and clock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friends and I are making a arena minigame where you fight to the death. I want to make it so that after thirty seconds (600 ticks), you get an ender pearl, and once you use the ender pearl, the timer goes back down to zero and you get another one after another thirty seconds. However, I have gotten stuck at the part where the player gets the ender pearl. Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
scoreboard objectives add Natan dummy
scoreboard objectives add NatanSuper dummy
scoreboard players add @a NatanSuper 1
execute if score 321nathango Natan >= 1 and if score 321nathango NatanSuper >= 600 NatanSuper run give 321nathango ender_pearl{display:{Name:'{"text":"Natan Super - Ender Pearl","color":"gold","bold":true,"italic":true}'},Enchantments:[{}]} 1
```

**Note:** `Natan` is intended to be an objective name, not a scoreholder. This is because Natan is a pickable role from a list of different characters, each having their own abilities and timers, hence having different objectives.

I am trying to make it so that it only gives it to you after the 600 ticks pass AND you have the 'Natan' scoreboard greater than or equal to 1. By the way, `321nathango` is my username that I am using for testing. It appears that even manually setting my scores to 1 and 600, nothing is happening.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: I have seen the same issue you are having quite a few times before on Arqade. I'd point you to another question showing the same problem with a good answer, but I'm having trouble finding the best question to point you towards. I'll answer your question below, and if anyone wants to give a good duplicate target for this, feel free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your last command, specifically this part:

```
execute if score 321nathango Natan >= 1 and if score 321nathango NatanSuper >= 600 NatanSuper run
```

The issue here is that you picked `>=`. You notice that at this point, you have six options: `<`, `<=`, `=`, `>`, `>=`, and `matches`. What they *don't* tell you is that the first five choices are for comparing one score with *another score*, not for comparing a score with a constant number.

This means that you are checking if the player `321nathango`'s `[Natan]` score is greater than or equal to the player `1`'s `[and]` score. It's treating the words `1 and` as a player name and objective name respectively, so it's trying to look up another score, specifically the objective named `and` (which doesn't exist), and the player named `1`.

If you want to compare a score with a constant number, use `matches` instead: this will allow you to enter a number instead of another player name and objective.

```
execute if score 321nathango Natan matches 1
```

And if you're curious how to do other comparisons other than a direct number match, that's done thru range notation:

- `5`: exactly 5
- `5..`: 5 or more
- `..5`: 5 or less
- `5..10`: 5 to 10

Comment: This seems like a poor alternative than just overloading the `>=` et al operators

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! It works!

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I mean, from the people that wrote the scoreboard interpreter and not being able to evaluate a score to a constant without matches. That is to say, your suggestion seems correct (and probably the *most correct* way) but it's unfortunate that the best way we have is not the best way possible and it's a shame the intuitive `if score 321nathango Natan >= 1` doesn't just work.

Comment: @corsiKa Commands are not a programming language. From the perspective of a commands developer, it makes sense to separate comparing scores vs comparing constants. It makes it important that we know exactly  what we want to do. Personally this isn't a problem to me.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Gonna have to disagree with you there - to me, anything fed into an `execute` command is absolutely a programming language. But, I'm happy to accept that we can't always change the world :)

Comment: @corsiKa Yeah, I guess `/execute` is like a little script in some ways. I would say, if you *really* wanted to use `>=`, you could just set a fake player to a number. For example, I would just do something like `if score #ticks timer >= #20 const`.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 It could be worse - the `matches` operator could be undocumented...

Comment: @corsiKa Agreed, that would be awful. Luckily [that isn't the case](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/execute#.28if.7Cunless.29_score), we clearly label *"symbol operators are to compare scores, `matches` to compare with constants."* (further discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk) plz?)